# JQuery - Upload Crop & Save To MySQL Database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html, file-upload

I am using the JQuery upload and crop plugin which can be found here:

http://www.webmotionuk.co.uk/jquery/image_upload_crop.php

The code works fine and as expected but the one change I wish to make is to insert the saved thumbnail name into a mysql table but for some reason I can't get this to work. It would be too much to post the full code so I will try and narrow it down:

**updateavatar.php** :

```
require("../db.php");

$avatar = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['avatar']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

mysql_query("UPDATE admin SET avatar='".$avatar."' WHERE email='".$email."'");
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I had to do something similar, and the only way I could figure out how to debug it was to print to the error_log in the php file. If you do `error_log($avatar. ' - ' .$email)` does it print what you're expecting to see? Also, you're not passing in a connection string to mysql_query, so I'm assuming you already have a connection open. If not, you need it. If you do have a connection, does the mysql_query function return true or false?

Comment: thanks guys but the `mysqlconnect` in the `db.php` which is included.
I added in the `error_log` but don't seem to get anything different.

Also, the way it fails is simply not updating the appropriate row in the database. I don't see any errors at all to do with syntax etc.

Comment: whoops, my mistake, it appears that the `error_log` prints out `admin` which is the user I am signed in as so it appears the variable for the filename is wrong.

From looking at the plug in code I was sure this was the right variable, hmmmmm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I received this message from WebMotionUk:

On version 1.2 of the script, on approximately line 246 (of the original file from the download) you should see this:

```
$cropped = resizeThumbnailImage($thumb_image_location, $large_image_location,$w,$h,$x1,$y1,$scale);
//Reload the page again to view the thumbnail
```

All you need to do is to add your database insert/update script directly below this line.

Therefore you should have the following:

```
$cropped = resizeThumbnailImage($thumb_image_location, $large_image_location,$w,$h,$x1,$y1,$scale);
mysql_query("UPDATE admin SET avatar='".$thumb_image_location."' WHERE    email='".$email."'"); 
//Reload the page again to view the thumbnail
```

Hope this helps anyone in the same situation.